# How to use timezone-js?

Tags: javascript, html

I saw this [project](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) in GitHub that converts a given timezone to another timezone.
I'm having difficulties on how to make this work. I downloaded the file and extracted it then created an html file as below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode" />
        <title>Time Zone Converter</title>
        <script src="timezone-js-master/src/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/jscript" language="jscript">
            function init() {
                var dt = new timezoneJS.Date("2012/04/10 10:10:30 +0000", 'Europe/London');
                dt.setTimezone("Asia/Jakarta");

                alert(dt);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">

    </body>
</html>
```

I expect that some message will popup but the above html doesn't actually work. Obviously I'm missing something.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the github comments, the constructor is not really clear.

There is also the added complexity of re-setting the perspective when passing your timezoneJS instance in a `new Date()` instance.

To get time date/time in another timezone you must instantiate, set the timezone using an Olson string, then get the *converted value* out of the timezoneJS instance.

So the following code:

```
var dt = new window.timezoneJS.Date(new Date());
console.debug(dt.toString());
dt.setTimezone('America/Los_Angeles');
console.debug(dt.toString());
```

Yields:

```
2013-07-18 19:09:30 //now
2013-07-18 16:09:30 //now... in LA
```